# Unable to find a default profile in CredentialProfileStoreChain?

Tags: c#, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, xunit.net

I get the Amazon.Runtime.AmazonServiceException when i try to run my unit test for the lambda I am writing. 
The lambda works fine and uses the profile credentials when i run it through Test function(AWS UI Test Function) or when i upload it in aws.
However when i try to run the unit test I get credentials not found error. I have tried other approach of trying to add the App.config with below details :

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="aws" type="Amazon.AWSSection, AWSSDK.Core" />
  </configSections>
  <aws 
    region="us-east-1" 
    profileName="default"
    profilesLocation="C:\Amazon\awsfile\credentials" />

</configuration>
```

by adding credentials in the file mentioned above. 
The exception is thrown when i debug below code:

```
var client = new AmazonDynamoDBClient();
```

Comment: I have this same issue.  i'm new to aws.  I'm REALLY confused as to why on earth one would need credentials to run unit tests.  How would this work with CI?

Comment: ah i figured it out.. it's complaining that you haven't set credentials to use the sdk - not necessarily that it's using those credentials for your tests.